# fetch data from multi tables with out relation ship between these tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

For every week I have excel sheet converted to SQL database this excel sheet gave me 30 deference table with same structure and field definition but there is no relationship between these tables.

So I want to merge the data from these 30 table in one table I'm trying to write T-sql to do this but I fail by `using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables` or `sys.tables` to get the table names and proceed to fetch data from these tables in one query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To combine tables together with the exact same schema:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table2
```

If your entire DB is made up of these tables you should be able to use the `sp_msforeachtable` procedure.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (Col1 INT, Col2 NVARCHAR(50))
sp_msforeachtable 'INSERT INTO #TempTable (Col1 , Col2) SELECT Col1 , Col2 FROM ?'
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Comment: There is a built in stored procedure, `sp_MSforeachtable`, that will allow you to look through all tables and dump into temp table. However it is selective, so it would do ALL tables in a DB.

Comment: sorry to trouble you Dustin, But I'm new with this sp so can you show me how can I use this sp

Comment: EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'INSERT into NewTable SELECT ''?'', FROM ?' is this right

Comment: Hi Dustin I'm take your query and edit it to exact what I want in my database its become like this (CREATE TABLE #TempTable ([f2] bigint, [f3] NVARCHAR(255),[f4] NVARCHAR(255),[f5] NVARCHAR(255))
exec sp_msforeachtable 'INSERT INTO #TempTable (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5) SELECT f1,f2,f3,f4,f5 FROM ?'
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
DROP TABLE #TempTable) but it return error invalid field name f1